# MVC4: Dynamic loading of cshtml file with jQuery.load

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Here's my situation: I have a project in which we were loading .aspx files dynamically, using the `jQuery.Load` function. We now have to use Razor instead, so I'm changing my aspx files to cshtml files.

The first obstacle was that I was given an error 500 when loading a cshtml with `jQuery.load()`. Did some research, and I added this line to my web.config

```
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />
```

That kinda fixed it, because I then got the following error message:

> ...cshtml' does not inherit from 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPage'.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.

So my fix was to add this to my cshtml file

```
@inherits System.Web.WebPages.WebPage
```

I can now load it with `jQuery.load()`, but I no longer have access to the MVC extension methods! (Example @Html.Partial), probably because it no longer inherits from `System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage`.

So here's my question: Is there anyway for me to have cshtml files that inherit from `System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage`, AND that can be loaded dynamically by `jQuery.Load()`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We always need a handler to process request first.

`.aspx` inherits System.web.ui.page which implements `IHttpHandler`

The `.cshtml` pages are used as a view inside a controller action execution. It is considered as a view file and does not implement IHttpHandler

Serve your .cshtml pages via some handler(controller)

Comment: Thanks! Do you have an example of that?